# Need opensource webapps to learn devops

Tags: web-applications, devops, open-source, cicd

i am new to learning devops. i want some open source web apps so that i can learn cicd and other devops practices. please suggest web apps from different frameworks like express, node , flask, django , spring boot etc so that i can get familier with all the stacks to learn devops. my requirements are the apps source code should be givin along with the backend information like ports, communcation protocols, etc so that i can run them locally and then implement devops practices.
thank you.